# Upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to 14.04.3, apt not recognizing new install of python 2.7.9

Tags: apt, updates, python, update-manager

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on a Dell T410 server, having upgraded from 10.10 (Maverick) earlier today. The upgrade went well for the most part, but I am having some difficulty using `apt-get upgrade`. Here is the exact error that I am getting:

```
tom@smckay1:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.restfulclient : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.uri : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyatspi : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
                  Depends: python-gi (>= 2.90.1)
                  Depends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libatk-adaptor but it is not installed
 python-simplejson : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-twisted-bin : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
 python-twisted-core : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                        Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zope.interface : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have tried multiple implementations of `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoremove`, and other similar measures. However, I keep getting that same error, and as a result, cannot install any new packages.

Here is my copy of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, with the comments removed. I admit that I did edit this file before the upgrade to include "trusty" instead of "lucid" when I did the OS upgrade from 10.10 to 14.04.

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release amd64 (20101007.1)]/ trusty main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy python`:

```
$ apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.6.6-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2.7.5-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I installed Python 2.7.9 using these commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz
tar -xvf Python-2.7.9.tgz
cd Python-2.7.9
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now, `python -V` tells me that I have version `2.7.9` installed, but `apt-get` doesn't see that. On a related note, during the upgrade, while running the `do-release-upgrade` command, I did get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 10, in <module>
 from UpdateManager.Core.DistUpgradeFetcherCore import      DistUpgradeFetcherCore
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/UpdateManager   /Core/DistUpgradeFetcherCore.py", line 34, in <module>
  import GnuPGInterface
ImportError: No module named GnuPGInterface
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 105,  in apport_excepthook
 os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL, 0600), 'w')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_bin_do-   release-upgrade.1001.crash'
```

Original exception was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 10, in <module>
from UpdateManager.Core.DistUpgradeFetcherCore import    DistUpgradeFetcherCore
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/DistUpgradeFetcherCore.py", line 34, in <module>
  import GnuPGInterface
 ImportError: No module named GnuPGInterface
```

However, a `sudo apt-get update` and upgrade eventually left me with Ubuntu 14.04 somehow.

Does anyone know what to do to resolve this? I really appreciate your help.

The output from `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
tom@smckay1:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for tom:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.restfulclient : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                            Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.uri : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyatspi : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
                  Depends: python-gi (>= 2.90.1)
                  Depends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libatk-adaptor but it is not installed
 python-simplejson : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-twisted-bin : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
 python-twisted-core : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                        Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zope.interface : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is installed
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

The output of `sudo apt-get install -f python`:

```
tom@smckay1:~$ sudo apt-get install -f python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 command-not-found : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 computer-janitor : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 computer-janitor-gtk : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 hplip : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
         Recommends: sane-utils but it is not going to be installed
 jockey-common : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 language-selector-common : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 lsb-release : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 nvidia-common : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python : Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: python-minimal (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 python-appindicator : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-apport : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-apt : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-aptdaemon : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
                    Recommends: aptdaemon but it is not going to be installed
 python-aptdaemon-gtk : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-brlapi : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-cairo : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-crypto : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-cups : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-dbus : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-egenix-mxdatetime : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-egenix-mxtools : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gconf : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-glade2 : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gmenu : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gnomeapplet : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gnomecanvas : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gnomekeyring : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gobject : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gobject-cairo : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gtksourceview2 : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-gtkspell : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-imaging : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-indicate : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-launchpad-integration : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-libxml2 : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-markupsafe : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-newt : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-notify : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-openssl : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-pam : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-problem-report : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-pyatspi : Depends: python-gi (>= 2.90.1)
                  Depends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libatk-adaptor but it is not going to be installed
 python-pycurl : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-pygoocanvas : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-pyorbit : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-rdflib : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-smbc : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-software-properties : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-twisted-web : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-ubuntuone : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-uno : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-virtkey : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-vte : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-webkit : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-wnck : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 python-xapian : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 screen-resolution-extra : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 ufw : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
 update-manager : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
                  Recommends: software-properties-gtk (>= 0.71.2) but it is not going to be installed
 update-manager-core : Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and dist-upgrade gives me the same output as apt-get upgrade (first code segment).

The output from `apt-cache policy command-not-found`:

```
command-not-found:
  Installed: 0.2.40ubuntu15
  Candidate: 0.3ubuntu12
  Version table:
     0.3ubuntu12 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.2.40ubuntu15 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Here is the output from `apt-get install command-not-found=0.3ubuntu12`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install command-not-found=0.3ubuntu12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 command-not-found : Depends: python3-commandnotfound (>= 0.3ubuntu7) but it is not going to be installed
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.restfulclient : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lazr.uri : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyatspi : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
                  Depends: python-gi (>= 2.90.1)
                  Depends: gir1.2-atspi-2.0 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libatk-adaptor but it is not going to be installed
 python-simplejson : Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-twisted-bin : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python-twisted-core : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                       Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                        Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zope.interface : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy command-not-found`:

```
$ apt-cache policy command-not-found
command-not-found:
  Installed: 0.2.40ubuntu15
  Candidate: 0.3ubuntu12
  Version table:
     0.3ubuntu12 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.2.40ubuntu15 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thank you for all the feedback so far.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Maybe there are, as the error suggests, held packages. Check with `apt-mark showhold`. With `sudo apt-get install -f --ignore-hold`, apt will ignore the hold status and install/upgrade packages regardless. This may already solve the dependency issue. For safety reasons you can always issue `apt-get...` with the switch `-s` to simulate what would happen.

Comment: @nephente, apt-mark showhold was not recognized by the command line, but the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` turned up no results. Unfortunately, `sudo apt-get install -f --ignore-hold` gave me the exact same results as `sudo apt-get install -f `.

Comment: I know that might not be possible, but consider reinstalling instead of upgrading for such old system.

Comment: Hmm, that would have been too easy. I guess you won't have any luck with `apt-get install -f python` ? Since you originally issued `apt-get upgrade` which is very conservative, how about `apt-get dist-upgrade` ? See the man page for differences. But somehow I fear this will fail as well.

Comment: @Marek, I am starting to consider doing that.

Comment: @nephente, I have run those two commands and am putting the output in the original post.

Comment: ehm. There is an upgrade path from Ubuntu 10.10 to 14.04? afaik you need to re-install to get from 10.10 to 14.04

Comment: And now the output of `apt-cache policy command-not-found`

Comment: @Rinzwind, if there is one, I am not aware of it.

Comment: @A.B. I have added the output of `apt-cache policy command-not-found`.

Comment: Ok, check my updated answer and give me a report =)

Comment: @A.B. Thank you for the commands. Unfortunately, both of the commands gave me the same error that I originally had.

Comment: [Edit] your question again and add the output of `sudo apt-get install command-not-found=0.3ubuntu12` and the output of `apt-cache policy command-not-found`

Comment: @A.B., I added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer in progress

First we have to repair your system:

- The first problematic package is `command-not-found`. You have the Precise version installed. Therefore start

  ```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

  This should upgrade the package and some others. Alternatively, we can force the installation of version `0.3ubuntu12` via

  ```
  sudo apt-get install command-not-found=0.3ubuntu12
  ```

---

The command

```
sudo make install
```

installs no packages. Therefore `apt` can't see the installed version.

If we have repaired your installation (therefore answer in progress), you can install the package later as follows.

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
cd ~/Downloads/Python-2.7.9
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: Any further feed-back since then?

Comment: @Fabby I need the output of another command :\ That will go a long way, but I'll get it. :)

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I ended up downloading a server edition of Ubuntu 14.04, burning the iso image to a DVD, and installing that from scratch (incorporating network connectivity so I could get as many package updates as possible) on the affected machine. Everything is hunky-dory now!